# Is there a word that refers to the sound made when we are moving in a type of terrain?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word that refers to the sound made when we are moving in a type of terrain? It should be a word that useful for video games, esp. 2d ones where moving through a grass or solid terrain result in a different sound being played. It doesn't necessarily have to be specific to video games, but it would be nice if the word was a specific word used by video game developers. I can't think of a word like that. For visuals, we have textures, but we don't have a word for a unit of sound, esp. that implies the same sound being played as a unit of sound at a trigger X.

For example:

> The ___ was repeatedly heard as Link walked in the tall grass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of specific words used for the specific sounds of particular terrain. For example:

> The rustle was repeatedly heard as Link walked in the tall grass.
>
> A crackle  was heard as Link walked in the dry brush.

I don't know of a word that is an audio equivalent of "texture".

Answer (score 0):

"Foley" is the closest word. (pronounced Foh-lee)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foley_(filmmaking)

It's not an exact fit because it includes all the non-musical effects. For example, the Foley would include weapon sounds.

Wikipedia claims that the overall Foley can be broken down into three categories, one of which ("feet") appears to be exactly what you're looking for. However, I have never heard those categories before, and I suspect they are jargon. It might be specifically what you want, but "Foley" would be recognizable to the general public, where "feet" would not be (at least, it would not mean "walking sounds" to most people).